# Intellij refactoring, disable/customize generating "@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull"

Tags: intellij-idea

Every time I extract method, this line is generated "for me":

```
@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
```

around the method. 1. I don't have this on my class path, so it does not compile 2. even if I have, I don't want to include jetbrains annotations in my project. Even if I have more suitable (maybe) `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` annotation on class path, intellij does not use that one.

questions:

1. how to turn it off entirely?
2. how to customize, which annotation to use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The extract method dialog has a `Generate annotations` check box. When disabled it does not generate the nullability annotations. The state of this check box is remembered between invocations, so disabling it once is enough.
[image: extract method dialog]

If this check box does not appear, annotations for the extracted method should not be generated.

It is possible to customize the annotation used in the settings of the `Java | Probable bugs | Constant conditions & exceptions` inspection. The configuration dialog looks this:
[image]
Use the check mark button, to mark the selected annotation as the one that should be used for code generation.

Comment: In the current Intellij version the extract method popup seems to have changed. The annotations checkbox is now located under the little gear wheel which is appearing when extract method is started.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem and was able to fix it by follow these steps :

Go to **Settings** > **Editor** > **Inspections** >

[image]

[image]

Find **Java** > **Probable Bugs** > **Nullability Problems** > **@NotNull/@Nullable Problems**

[image]

[image]

Click **Configure Annotations** button and check these items

[image]