# IntelliJ - How to disable generation of `@NotNull` annotation?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I extract a method, IDEA generates code like this:

```
@NotNull
private String getSimpleName(TestInfo testInfo) {
  return testInfo.getTestClass().get().getSimpleName();
}
```

I don't want IDEA to generate the `@NotNull` annotation - in my project everything is assumed to be "not null" by default.

I've added my own custom `@Nullable` annotation in the "Nullable/NotNull Configuration" dialog - but it seems like one of the annotations in the "NotNull Annotations" section always has to be selected.

I've looked in the "File and Code Templates" section - neither "Implemented Method Body" nor "New Method Body" template contains the `@NotNull` code.

How do I tell IDEA that everything is "@NotNull" be default and it should not generate an annotation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij refactoring, disable/customize generating "@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64424230/intellij-refactoring-disable-customize-generating-org-jetbrains-annotations-n)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/. "Generate annotations" option should be available there:
[image]